# Rails API, JSON - how to connect to a web app and bring tables to life?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

**Hello!**

First of all I would like to let you know that I am a fairly new to programming (mostly **Ruby on Rails**). I have been studying by myself for around 6 months. I recently got a first project - a voting app.

I have created the layout to the app - using **HTML**, **CSS**, **bootstrap**, a little **JS** and **JQuery**.

Now I need to bring the app to life - so, make the tables alive. I have heard that it shouldn't be hard to do in **Rails API** (using **REST**), which I have created with the help of some tutorials (like [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P8gGJBIiLGI&t=752s)). The webapp will be used only **locally**, on a device.

So, my questions is:

**How to connect Rails API to the layout and make it "talk" to eachother?**

I know I should use JSON to communicate the front end with server, but I am not sure where to start.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to develop 2 create 2 different apps? One to work as a client and another as api?

Comment: I have created a layout, now I need to make it alive and store data in tables. Can I do this without an api then? I am sorry if this is stupid question.

Comment: You can always create a form and insert data into tables using rails mvc architecture. If you want to use rails api, there can be two ways of doing it, one using the resource api as shown in the tutorial u shared which will need specific data format body and headers. Else if you are more comfortable with mvc, use jbuilder gem as ur view instead of html which will give you flexibility of definibg ur own controllers and parameters. I would suggest different app for api which will be used fir fetching and storing the data, and different for client which will only render data.

Comment: So, if I am more comfortable with MVC it would be better to create this app using Rails as always? There will be no drawbacks  or slows if I use this app on the raspberry pi with a streaming python script? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes..it is just that api helps to eliminate client side dependencies n more flexibility. PS i would appreciate an upvote if it helped u.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will give you an upvote as soon as I will have 15 points so I can do this!

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to make a website you should follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nf_Si8_szmM). APIs are more for sharing your sites data or functionality with other sites, or for serving data to mobile apps/frontend frameworks like AngularJS.